# Deploying Hello-world Python Flask in Azure App Service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask, azure-appservice

i am trying to deploy hello world flask app in Azure App Service through Vscode.
But After deployment while browsing the URL , i am getting following error

[image]

The Folder Structure look like this , in app service editor

[image]

My Web config File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="application.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
 </appSettings>
 <system.webServer>
 <handlers>
   <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" 
  scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py" 
  resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

my application.py code is

```
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
 def hello_world():
     return "Hello Updated World!"

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

what I need to do so that clicking my app url , i will be able to see "Hello Updated World"..

I am using window , python 3.6 in web app ..

In deployment center it is showing deployment Successful.
[image]

My App Setting
[image]

Process explorer in kuddu
[image]

Comment: did you try to use the devops starter to deploy ?

Comment: how to use devops starter  ...

Comment: search for devops starter project in the market place

Comment: can you open kudu and see if the app is running

Comment: @Sajeetharan, i think it is running, added the screen shot from process explorer in kuddu

Comment: if its running you should be able to see

Comment: do you have a starting file index.html?